# Indexing: Do I have too many indices?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of lessons, which contains document with the following schema

```
{
    title: "Programming 101",
    category: 1
    likes: 10,
    author: {
        name: "Mike",
        reputation: 100,
        rating: 1500
    },
    created: 154895126, // unix timestamp
    content: ".... html ... "
}
```

In the index page of my application, I display the latest 18 lessons from all categories, so this is

```
db.lessons.find().sort({created:-1}).limit(18)
```

As this is a very common query and the lessons collection will be my biggest collection in the system, I want to optimize it as much as possible, so I made an index on *created*

```
db.lessons.ensureIndex({created:-1})
```

But sometimes I want to get just lessons from one category

```
db.lessons.find({category:1}).sort({created:-1}).limit(18)
```

So I also added an index in category, because if I dont, mongo can sort easily, but it will still have to check element by element to get the one with category = 1, so

```
db.lessons.ensureIndex({category:1})
```

Because I don't sort by category, I just pass a 1, for ascending order.

Now, the problem is I also want to sort lessons by likes, author's reputation, and author's rating, these will be very common tasks, not as common as sort by created, but still very common, should I add 3 more indices? Or just use the created one?

```
db.lessons.ensureIndex({likes:-1})
db.lessons.ensureIndex({'author.reputation':-1})
db.lessons.ensureIndex({'author.rating':-1})
```

I feel I might use too many indices, and the collection size in memory might be huge.

Comment: is there a reason your second index isn't {category:1, created:-1}? without the second part the sort has to happen in memory which is more intensive and slower.

Comment: could you also add information about how many documents you will have (approximate max) and whether the sorting you will allow will be on the full result set or only within each subcategory?

Answer (score 5):

I'll third asya's motion for an aggregate index.

```
> db.lessons.ensureIndex({category:1});
> db.lessons.ensureIndex({created:-1});
> db.lessons.find({category:1}).sort({created:-1}).limit(18).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor category_1",
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "n" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "category" : [
            [
                1,
                1
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Here explain() illustrates that MongoDB will not utilize both individual indexes in the way we might expect an SQL database would.

```
> db.lessons.ensureIndex({category:1,created:-1});
> db.lessons.find({category:1}).sort({created:-1}).limit(18).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor category_1_created_-1",
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "n" : 1,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "category" : [
            [
                1,
                1
            ]
        ],
        "created" : [
            [
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

The aggregate index looks like a winner for sure.

As for the concern about too many indexes, for my day job I'm working with a collection which has over 38 million documents with table scans disabled via the --notablescan option. We've found that it's essential for us to have an index tailored for each query.

Answer (score 0):

If you mentioned that

> these will be very common tasks

than in my opinion you should use indices, because otherwise your query will go through all the documents in your collection before giving the result. Of course to answer more precisely one must know the number of your collection and of course some metric regarding "common thing". And for sure that the best way to decide how you should behave is to run some tests.

Collect the information how the user behave in some period of time (2 days period) and check how many times each type of queries appeared. Than you will now the 'commonness' of each one. Than simulate these type of queries with and without indices and check what works better.

And also I agree with @Asya regarding here reply

> is there a reason your second index isn't {category:1, created:-1}